# using Python to change MAC address

Tags: python, linux

I am a beginner. I am trying to write a code which will help me to change my MAC address, but when I run this python code

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sudo ifconfig",shell=True) # shutdown interface`
```

it asks me for the password for sudo.

Please help me to write code to enter the password from the Python script and pass this etape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can adhere to best practices and use the accepted method to communicate with subprocesses.

```py
import subprocess


out = subprocess.run('sudo -S ls', shell=True, input=b'123', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(out.stdout)
```

You can read extensively about this method of operations in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) but a few words about it:
It is much easier to program around because you have the usual coding tools you'd expect. Such as exceptions and return values.

In the above example we use the recommended `-S` that tells `sudo` to use the regular `stdin` communication channel to accept intput data. Every process comes with 3 communication channels, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. Their names imply their intent. `stdin` for input, `stdout` for normal output (no errors), `stderr` for output meant to indicate errors. Sensitive input do not use the regular `stdin` which is what `sudo` was suggesting in your error message.

We ask `subprocess.run` to use a new `stdout` channel with the syntax `subprocess.PIPE`. Because, otherwise, it inherits the same communication channels from its parent (the Python script) and the `sudo -S ls` command output will immediately be dumped to the Python script output. Which is, usually, undesired.

Lastly, we print the results.

Answer (score -1):

For this, it is best to use pexpect (install with `pip install pexpect`):

```
import pexpect
pipe = pexpect.spawn("sudo ifconfig")
pipe.expect_exact("[sudo] password for kali: ")
pipe.sendline("your_password")
pipe.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
```

Comment: thank you my dear for your answer
can you please explain to me what every line do

Comment: Welcome. Using `pexpect` is very bad practice and wildly discouraged.

Comment: Yeah, now that I realize, it is not a good idea to hardcode the password in.

Comment: @OngYongXin You're right, that too. But, specifically using pexpect can easily create "hidden" bugs. You're heavily broadening the language lexicon between your function and pexpect with many specific strings. Rather than using more focused inter-process communications. A similar anti-pattern method of work is catching Exception and parsing the string to evaluate the error. Rather than using Exception subclassed types to determine what happened. In more administrative terms, it increases development costs.

Comment: @edd, of course assuming OP is using it in production code, then yes.